# How to properly convert hsl colors to rgb colors in lua?

Tags: colors, lua, rgb, hsl

I have the following code:

```lua
#!/usr/bin/env lua5.3
-- Code adapted from https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/columns/blob/master/utils/color.lua#L51

local function hslToRgb(h, s, l, a)
    local r, g, b

    h = (h / 255)
    s = (s / 100)
    l = (l / 100)

    if s == 0 then
        r, g, b = l, l, l -- achromatic
    else
        local function hue2rgb(p, q, t)
            if t < 0   then t = t + 1 end
            if t > 1   then t = t - 1 end
            if t < 1/6 then return p + (q - p) * 6 * t end
            if t < 1/2 then return q end
            if t < 2/3 then return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6 end
            return p
        end

        local q
        if l < 0.5 then q = l * (1 + s) else q = l + s - l * s end
        local p = 2 * l - q

        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3)
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h)
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3)
    end

    if not a then a = 1 end
    return r * 255, g * 255, b * 255, a * 255
end

local h,s,l,a
h,s,l,a = hslToRgb(220, 16.4, 21.6)

print(h,s,l,a)
-- expected output: 46  52  64  255
--   actual output: 64.11312    46.04688    60.92496    255
```

But, as stated at the end, the color values it outputs are completely wrong. The decimals are not an issue (as in, it's not an issue that it outputs them; their values are still wrong).

Comment: I do not have time to debut. Could you write the value it give you the algorithm, for white, black, red, yellow, green, blue and mid-gray). Usually with such data you should understand the differences (possibly a different convention: linear/gamma corrected; angle of zero, direction of hue, range (but in this case it seems clear). And also with that, there are different intepretation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hue value it's calculated in degrees, so the max isn't 255, but 360:

```
function hslToRgb(h, s, l)
    h = h / 360
    s = s / 100
    l = l / 100

    local r, g, b;

    if s == 0 then
        r, g, b = l, l, l; -- achromatic
    else
        local function hue2rgb(p, q, t)
            if t < 0 then t = t + 1 end
            if t > 1 then t = t - 1 end
            if t < 1 / 6 then return p + (q - p) * 6 * t end
            if t < 1 / 2 then return q end
            if t < 2 / 3 then return p + (q - p) * (2 / 3 - t) * 6 end
            return p;
        end

        local q = l < 0.5 and l * (1 + s) or l + s - l * s;
        local p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1 / 3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1 / 3);
    end

    if not a then a = 1 end
    return r * 255, g * 255, b * 255, a * 255
end
```

You can see this code working [here](https://lua.ceifa.tv/?paste=ohefopudac).

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
-- HSV to RGB
min = math.min
max = math.max
abs = math.abs

local function HSV2RGB (h, s, v)
    local k1 = v*(1-s)
    local k2 = v - k1
    local r = min (max (3*abs (((h      )/180)%2-1)-1, 0), 1)
    local g = min (max (3*abs (((h  -120)/180)%2-1)-1, 0), 1)
    local b = min (max (3*abs (((h  +120)/180)%2-1)-1, 0), 1)
    return k1 + k2 * r, k1 + k2 * g, k1 + k2 * b
end
```

Comment: perfect! it returns values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a more elegant solution to the HSV to RGB problem for a little bit now and this is what I've come up with.

```
local ceil = math.ceil
local abs = math.abs

local function clamp(v, min, max)
    if v < min then return min end
    if v > max then return max end
    return v
end

local function HSV(h, s, v)
    local vert = ceil(h / 120)
    local r = abs(((h / 60) - 2 * vert))
    local r, g, b = clamp(r, 1 - s, 1), clamp(2 - r, 1 - s, 1), (1 - s * v)

    if vert == 1 then return r, g, b end
    if vert == 2 then return b, r, g end
    if vert == 3 then return g, b, r end
end
```